# How can I deploy a node js API that uses the whatsapp-web.js package in Vercel?

Tags: node.js, vercel, whatsapp

[api.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISo8e.png)

I am trying to make an API to send whatsapp messages using the whatsapp-web.js package but when I upload it to Vercel it no longer runs the program. Does anyone know how I can make the deploy correctly? I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: Give a link to your code files or attach code here. Also, attach your vercel logs. Explain your question further.

Comment: @Niusoski all code relevant to the question should be in the question, not linked off-site. Links can rot or be inaccessible for other reasons which would render the question incomprehensible for future visitors.